# Impact of deleting the custom fields with upgraded ManagedPackage

Tags: managed-package, custom-field, package, custom

The ManagedPackage (Ex: MPV1)  with few custom fields(Ex: C1,C2,C3,C4) in Account Object is created and installed in an instance(I1). I wanted to remove few customfields(Ex: C3 and C4) and recreate the ManagedPackage(Ex: MPV2), upgrade the already installed package MPV1 to MPV2 in the instance(I1).
So, now i would like to know the impact of the custom fields after upgrade.

1. What happens to the **page layouts** that may have the fields C3 and C4
2. What happens to C3 and C4 custom fields if it contains already **contains data** in the instance ? Will there be any problem with the fields while upgrading with new ManagedPackage(MPV2).
3. If its a custom object with data. What will be the behavior of upgraded Managed Package.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simple delete a field and remove it from manage package. Once a field is part of Managed package (Release) you can only change few attribute of this.
The component, once added to a package, can't be deleted.

If you need to remove a component then you first need to remove reference from all places (including class/pages) and then contact Salesforce support. They will change the Package type to Beta. Also if this package is installed somewhere then you need to get it uninstalled it from there as well.

So once you manually removed all reference of that fields you don't need to worry about anything else.

[Remove components from a Managed Package](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=How-do-I-remove-components-from-a-Managed-Package-1327108663841&language=en_US&type=1)